# Hide a django model field and generate it myself on form submit

Tags: python, django

I have a model with the following Fields:
`alert_text`, 
`next_run` (next time alert will pop out)

the `next_run` is auto filled by me (I dont want to user to fill it) so I hide it like so:

```
#admin.py
class AlertForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Alert
        fields =  '__all__'



class AlertAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AlertForm
    fields = ['alert_text']

admin.site.register(Alert,AlertAdmin)
```

The problem is that now I can't find a way to add it to the model when created. and I get an Error:

`'AlertForm' has no field named 'next_run'.`

this is the model.py:

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    alert_text= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    next_run = models.DateTimeField()
```

Will appreciate any help here couldn't find a solution anywhere :(

Comment: Can you show the code where you get the error? How are you generating the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you do not need the AlertForm class.

You can just define, `AlertAdmin`, in your admin.py file like this:

```
class AlertAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('alert_text', 'next_run',)
    exclude = ('next_run',)
```

and then register the AlertAdmin class with this line in your admin.py file.

```
admin.site.register(Alert, AlertAdmin)
```

Then in your definition of your Alert model override the save method ... for example:

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    alert_text= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    next_run = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):

        self.next_run = datetime.datetime.now()
        super(Alert, self).save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
```